# More than Like Statement in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dml

why this work :

```
SELECT * FROM Companies  WHERE CompanyCode LIKE '%' AND BusinessUnitShortName LIKE 'CO%'
```

while mean this not work :

```
DECLARE @WHERECondition NVARCHAR(200) = ''
SET @WHERECondition = '''%'' AND BusinessUnitShortName LIKE ''CO%'''

SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE CompanyCode LIKE  @WHERECondition
SELECT  @WHERECondition
```

Comment: Because a column name can't be included in a variable unless you're using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make that work you need to use the dynamic sql like

```
DECLARE @WHERECondition NVARCHAR(200) = ''
SET @WHERECondition = '''%'' AND BusinessUnitShortName LIKE ''CO%'''
declare @sql nvarchar(Max)

Set @sql='SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE CompanyCode LIKE'+@WHERECondition

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

If you are not using the dynamic sql then you need to provide the column names as the SQL parser will look for the columns at the time when it is parsing the query and if not found will result in error.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use dynamic SQL to achieve what you want.  Your current method gets evaluated to something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Companies 
WHERE CompanyCode LIKE '''%'' AND BusinessUnitShortName LIKE ''CO%'''
```

What you actually want is more like this:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @WHERECondition =  '''%'' AND BusinessUnitShortName LIKE ''CO%'''

SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE CompanyCode LIKE ' + @WHERECondition
EXEC(@sql);
```

which would evalute to:

```
SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE CompanyCode LIKE '%' AND BusinessUnitShortName LIKE 'CO%'
```